# Filter a string if it's found in a list

Tags: python

I've created a wrapper for logging in Python & want to ignore certain strings. I believed you could simply do something like `if msg in FILTER` to match a string in a list of strings.

So I tried this;

```
FILTER = ["Couldn't eval", "wrapWithType"]

class LegacyLogger(logging.Logger):
    def legacydebug(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Log messages.

        @param msg: Information to log
        @type msg: str
        """
        if not any(msg in s for s in FILTER):    # also tried 'if not msg in FILTER'
            self._log(LEGACY_DEBUG_LVL, msg, '')

    logging.Logger.legacydebug = legacydebug
```

But this isn't working as my log features lines like 'Couldn't eval Y because of name 'Y' is not defined' so does this look for a total match on the string and not a partial match?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `for any(msg if s in msg else None for s in FILTER)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is `if not any(s in msg for s in FILTER):`.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to reverse it I think, try:

`if any([s in msg for s in FILTER]):`

You were trying to match the whole msg to a string in filter, which doesn't give you any matches.